# three dimensional vs singe dimensional array in php

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

For one of my project, the marks scored by the individual students to be designed. there are 4 class (7th, 8th 9th and 10th)  and in each class, there are around 25 students (their Roll_No are: 1001,1002,1003,1004...) The marks scored  are given in serial as: Physics, chemistry, maths and English.

The Three dimensional array for above marks:

```
$marks = array(
    "7" => array(
        "1001" => array(90, 95, 98, 78),
        "1002" => array(91, 90, 93, 77),
        "1003" => array(88, 83, 90, 68),
        "1004" => array(90, 91, 90, 80)
        ),
    "8" => array(
        "1001" => array(88, 90, 95, 77),
        "1002" => array(91, 92, 94, 75),
        "1003" => array(90, 90, 95, 66),
        "1004" => array(90, 92, 88, 70)
        ),
     ..................................
     ..................................
    "10" => array(
        "1001" => array(81, 91, 95, 79),
        "1002" => array(92, 92, 95, 85),
        "1003" => array(91, 90, 91, 62),
        "1004" => array(88, 90, 89, 78)
        )
    );
```

Instead of putting these details in three-dimensional array, I put the same in single dimensional array -like:

```
//class, Roll_no, physics, chemistry, maths, English
    $marks = array(7, 1001, 90, 95, 98, 78),
                  (7, 1002, 91, 90, 93, 77),
                  (7, 1003, 88, 83, 90, 68),
                  (7, 1004, 90, 91, 90, 80), 
                  (8, 1001, 88, 90, 95, 77),
                  (8, 1002, 91, 92, 94, 75),
                  (8, 1003, 90, 90, 95, 66),
                  (8, 1004, 90, 92, 88, 70)
     );
```

My HTML code is:

```
<form method="post" name="data" action="mark.php">
Enter class:  
  <select name="class">
      <option value="7"> 7th Class 
      <option value="8"> 8th Class
      <option value="9"> 9th Class
      <option value="10"> 10th Class
  </select>
<br> Enter Roll no: 
  <select name="roll_no">
      <option value="1001"> Roll no:1001
      <option value="1002"> Roll no:1002
      <option value="1003"> Roll no:1003
      <option value="1004"> Roll no:1004
  </select>
<br><input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

My PHP code is:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $roll_no = $_POST['roll_no'];

    $ans1 = $marks[$class][$roll_no][2]; // marks in Physics
    $ans2 = $marks[$class][$roll_no][3]; // marks in chemistry
    $ans3 = $marks[$class][$roll_no][4]; // marks in maths
    $ans4 = $marks[$class][$roll_no][5]; // marks in english

    echo "The marks scored in Physics by Roll no: $roll_no (Class: $class th): $ans1 <br>";
    echo "The marks scored in Chemistry by Roll no: $roll_no (Class: $class th): $ans2 <br>";
    echo "The marks scored in Maths  by Roll no: $roll_no (Class: $class th): $ans3 <br>";
    echo "The marks scored in English by Roll no: $roll_no (Class: $class th): $ans4 <br>";
}
```

But it is showing error. Can any body help me in correcting the code please?

Comment: I think it is better to add in 3 dimensional array, than in single dimensional array. In Single dimension, you have to loop through the entire array in all the times. If in 3 dimensional you can access the data like `#marks["class"]['serial_no'][2]`.

Comment: Your code is wrong. Because, ` $ans1 = $marks[$class][$roll_no][2]` is a pattern for 3 dimensional array. If you use it in single dimensional array, PHP can't find the index you specified and will show error.

Comment: Loping is better option than putting the entire data in three dimensional, more over, saves lot of work.  The code is again edited

Comment: It saves lot of work, but once you done it, then your code will be much faster as it avoid the looping. Or if you have 2000 records, each time the loop execute 2000 times. And if u done 5 search, the loop will run 10000 times.

Comment: Is there any better way like: JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code if you prefer looping

```
$count = sizeof($marks);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    if($marks[$i][0] == $class && $marks[$i][1] == $$roll_no)
{
   echo 'Yes';
}
}
```

Comment: As you said, looping will execute several times for each search, I want better option than 3-dimensional array (like, ajax /JSON) could you consider?  <br/>

Comment: Whether the switch case is better one? as the condition meets, the code will execute the results rather  checking all the conditions

Comment: @user2591029: I'm not sure whether there is a better way. For this purpose of course you need some kind of looping or array mechansm.. AJAX and json also will work like the same..